# Find Torque and Force on Pipe with Bend

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pipelines

I did a Civil Engineering course some years ago and from my textbook I had a question on a pipe with a bend. 
Now I think I have the part of the question on force correct, but I am not sure how the torque will be calculated in this situation. 
Can someone please help and give me an idea as to how to work this out?

I have the question as an image with my calculations below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you know how to calculate the forces due to a fluid flow? At the outlet, you must simply consider the momentum equation (Newton's Second Law), to find the axial force at said outlet - the torque then is simply this force multiplied by 1.7 (the perpendicular distance from the pivot, 'A').

[image: Torque radius diagram]

Comment: Jonathon R Swift
I have tried to reply to you, but system does not let me do this.
I want to clarify about torque, as you have only covered part (a).

From question is flow going down the vertical main and into pipe D and pipe C?

Why do we use r = 2.4 * sin45 = 1.7 to multiply by force to get torque for part (a)?
I can see that if I take my 1453.17 N and multiply by 2.4 * sin 45, I get torque of 2466 N.
If I do it with the Force Answer of 1454 N, I get torque of 2468 N which agrees with answer.
You have not shown me how to get torque for part (b) when pipe tapers from 150mm to 100mm,

Comment: In both cases you need to calculate the force as a result of the fluid leaving the exit of pipe C - because it is tapered in case b), the fluid will exit with less momentum compared to case a), meaning that there is a lower torque.

Comment: Jonathon R Swift
Thanks for that, I thought it is flowing down the vertical and leaving exit at pipe C.

You haven't answered my part about about why force is multiplied by  r = 2.4 * sin45 in part (a)?

Also Why is the torque less than the force in part (b) ? 
Is the distance calculated differently for part (b) ?
Is torque also calculated in a slightly different way because of the tapering in part (b) ?

Comment: The distance is identical - it’s the momentum of the fluid exiting through the smaller orifice that has changed!

Comment: Hi Jonathon R Swift

Can you please show me in step by step calculation for part (b) how this works to find torque ?
I am confused because torque is less than force for part (b)

Comment: The torque is calculated from a  different force! The "force" part in the question is the force on A in the direction D. The force that causes the torque is due to the fluid leaving at position C in the direction BC!

Comment: Hi Jonathon
Just trying to get an understanding on how you calculate that force due to the fluid leaving in direction BC for the torque.

Would you calculate it like this: 

Force at C = p1 * A1 / sin 45 - p2 * A2 / sin 45 + Rho * Q (V1 / sin 45 - V2)

where p1 and p2 are pressures at A and and these cause force due to pressure
and Rho * Q (V1 / sin 45 - V2) is from momentum change

If I am not correct with what I have said, may you please show me with steps how this is calculated?

Comment: Hi Jonathon R Swift

Have you seen my reply, just still stumped on the torque part for when pipe tapers.
Are you able to show me with calculations how this works ?

Comment: Hi Jonathon Swift

Have you had the chance to look at my last 2 replies.
Still haven't got my head around how you get the correct answer for torque for part b.
You said the force for working out torque is leaving the pipe at bc.
Just wondering if you could please show me with some calculations how this should work.
I am nearly here with this question and don't won't it to take a long time to work it out, just because I am busy with other things.
Hope you understand.
Really appreciative of the help so far.

Comment: Hi Jonathon R Swift

May you please reply to my comments.
Replying to someones comments is polite.

Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 0):

[image: Question 28]

I am just working on the torque for part (b) and will have the rest of this answer up , as soon as I can.

The force to calculate torque is the force in the 45 degree direction from B to C.

Comment: Your handwriting part is blurred. Please find a better method to post it, and clearly identify the calculated forces for (a) and (b). Thanks.